# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-views

I'm encountering an issue with jQuery's $.ajax function in my web application. When I try to make an AJAX request using $.ajax, I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function" in the browser console.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/add-to-wishlist",
    data: {"id": product_id},
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(){
        console.log("Adding to wishlist");
    },
    success: function(response){
        this_val.html("");
        if (response.bool === true) {
            console.log("Added to wishlist");
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        console.log(errmsg);
    }
});
```

I've ensured that jQuery is properly included in my HTML file before including my JavaScript file. However, I'm still encountering this error.

Could anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to verify that `$` is correctly bound to the jQuery main function. There are ways that can be broken: other scripts can un-bind the symbol, for example.

Comment: If you post a portion of your HTML that imports the scripts, it might become evident what's going on.

Comment: Yes I verified that `$` is correctly bound to the jQuery main function. and also I updated the problem please check it out

Comment: It looks like you edited in a completely different question.

Comment: If `$` really were bound to jQuery, you would not be having the problem with `$.ajax`. How **exactly** have you verified it?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in the same post! One post should only have one question. If the code you had shared was about this same question here please [edit] with a proper [mre] and explanation that the code is related to the same error you got.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It appears like jQuery is not being used in your web project. These are the two typical methods for doing so:

1. Download from Official Library: You can download jQuery directly from the official website and include it in your project. You can download it from jQuery's official website [Click](https://jquery.com/%20download/#jquery) .
2. Using CDN (Content Delivery Network): Alternatively, you can include jQuery via a CDN link directly in your HTML file. Here's an example of how you can include jQuery from the Google CDN:

```js
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: From the question: *I've ensured that jQuery is properly included in my HTML file before including my JavaScript file.*

Comment: How have you made sure jQuery is included correctly? One more thing that will happen is that your file may have been sent or something else will happen before jQuery loads.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like jQuery isn't correctly initialized when your script runs, or you're using a slim version of jQuery which doesn't include the `$.ajax` function. Double-check the version of jQuery you're including; make sure it's not the slim version. Also, ensure jQuery is loaded before your script tries to use `$.ajax`. You can verify it by logging `jQuery` or `$` in the console before your AJAX call. If it's undefined, that's your cue to recheck the script tags' order in your html.